# Android Listview Item remove but adapter not getting set and item is still showing?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have this code on `Button` click

I am removing item from `ListView` but problem is its still showing on adapter.

```
restaurants_bean_arr.remove(restaurants_bean_arr.get(item_position).facilities.get(item_position).getUrl());
                     restaurants_bean_arr.remove(restaurants_bean_arr.get(item_position).facilities.get(item_position).getName());
    DisplayDataAdapter adapter = new DisplayDataAdapter(getApplicationContext());           
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Any Idea what could be the problem that item is not getting removing from object class `ArrayList`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Switch order of:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

To:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Not working if I do change the order. I would it was working great when i was using local array list . but restaurant_bean_arr is my Object class array list and I dont know why its nit working with object class array list

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are creating a new `Adapter` every time you change your dataset and set this new `Adapter` to your `ListView`. You don't have to do that. You can just make changes to your dataset and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter`.

So your code should look like this:

```
restaurants_bean_arr.remove(restaurants_bean_arr.get(item_position).facilities.get(item_position).getUrl()); 
restaurants_bean_arr.remove(restaurants_bean_arr.get(item_position).facilities.get(item_position).getName());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is problem

```
 DisplayDataAdapter adapter = new DisplayDataAdapter(getApplicationContext());
```

you are creating a new adapter. Create a global value adapter and try like this:

```
restaurants_bean_arr.remove(restaurants_bean_arr.get(item_position).facilities.get(item_position).getUrl());
                 restaurants_bean_arr.remove(restaurants_bean_arr.get(item_position).facilities.get(item_position).getName());
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: If I do that global declaration then its giving me nullpointer exception ... sorry not working this solution

Comment: İt shouldnt give i mean create this as global: "DisplayDataAdapter adapter" and set it at the beggining(onCreate())  adapter = new DisplayDataAdapter(this); and set it to listview. Then try my answer it should not give nullpointer